# addEventListener not working JS HTML

Tags: javascript, html, button, submit, addeventlistener

The first button works but the other doesn't.

HTML

```
<button class="btn btn-success randomize">Randomize</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary submit">Submit</button>
```

---

JS

```
var submit = document.querySelector('.submit');
var randomize = document.querySelector('.randomize');


submit.addEventListener('click', onSubmit);
randomize.addEventListener('click', randomize);

function randomize(){
console.log('work');
}

function onSubmit(){
    console.log('submitted');
}
```

The "submit" button works but the "randomize" button doesn't. Why is this?

Comment: Super odd. Renaming function to `randomize2` makes it work for me: https://jsfiddle.net/t2fj84v2/ I guess because the other variable is named randomize too. Thanks @gerardo

Comment: The name of your function `randomize` is the same as your variable. You're re declaring. Change the name.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!!!!!!!!!!!